# Can't add keyboard layout on Debian remote desktop

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, remote, vnc

I want to enable Russian keyboard layout on a Debian remote desktop (connected with Xvnc). `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` changed `/etc/default/keyboard` as desired:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp:switch,grp_led:scroll"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Then

```
aromanov@ws:~/IdeaProjects/scalan$ sudo service keyboard-setup restart
[ ok ] Setting preliminary keymap...done.
aromanov@ws:~/IdeaProjects/scalan$ sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change # produces no output
```

The new layout doesn't show up in `System Settings > Keyboard > Layout settings` and `Ctrl+Shift` doesn't work. I've also tried setting it directly from the terminal:

```
aromanov@ws:~/IdeaProjects/scalan$ setxkbmap ru
XKB extension not present on :2
```

Googling doesn't give anything too useful, unfortunately. Can I fix this (e.g. by passing some arguments to `Xvnc` or changing `~/.vnc/xstartup`)?

Comment: I know of no X server providing the VNC protocol which has the XKB extension.

Comment: @AProgrammer Are there other remote desktop protocols which can provide it?

Comment: The issue is not the VNC protocol, it is the implementation of Xvnc.  I've not looked at this for years (that's why I didn't give an answer, I haven't done the minimal research to provide something more than an outdated recollection).